# Using variables as properties

Tags: asp.net, linq

So, I'm using LINQ in ASP.NET 4.0 to access my DB.

I have the following line of code:

```
var h = (from p in DB.d_tblDrinks where p.drinkID == _drinkID && p.drinkShow select p).First();
```

But i would like to access the property (eg. drinkID) with a variable, so i did this:

```
string prop = "drinkID";
var h = (from p in DB.d_tblDrinks where p.prop == _drinkID && p.drinkShow select p).First();
```

This is not possible, but is there some/similar way that makes it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [Dynamic Linq Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

You can download the LINQ Dynamic Query Library there and view a number of examples.

Then you can write completely dynamic LINQ queries.